# Sort Java Map based on values in another map

Tags: java, dictionary, linked-list, linkedhashmap

As an input, I have List of objects, each object has name and map:

```
1)
  Name: m1

  Map: {"c1": 3,
 "c2": 24
 "c3": 12}

2) Name: m2

Map: {"c1": "A",
 "c2": "B",
 "c3": "C"}

3) Name: m3

Map: {"c1": 3.4,
 "c2": 4.6,
 "c3": 12.3}
```

**What I need as an output, I need to sort all 3 maps based on values in map with name m1**.

So first, I want to sort map for object#1(**m1**) **by values in descending orders** (I can use LinedHashMap here):

```
{"c1": 3, "c2": 24, "c3": 12}  =>  {"c2": 24, "c3": 12, "c1": 3}
```

And now, I want elements in map for object#2 and map for object#3, also be sorted in the same key orders - C2, C3, C1. So basically I want reorder 2 maps so that order is C2, C3, C1 (the same order as in **m1**), and **NOT** C1, C2, C3.

*How can I do it most elegant way?* I have some solutions - but they are messy, and have a lot of extra steps.

If it's matter: this list will always have only 3 objects. Number of elements in Map can be different, but keys in maps will always be the same across 3 maps

Comment: @ram. `TreeMap` can be sorted.

Comment: @tsolakp No it can't. It *is* sorted, already, on its keys. You cannot sort maps on their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you know how to sort a `Map` by value, maybe by reading this answer: [Sort a Map by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2581754/5221149), where the Java 8 version of the answer is:

> ```
> m1sorted = m1.entrySet()
>              .stream()
>              .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Collections.reverseOrder()))
>              .collect(Collectors.toMap(
>                Map.Entry::getKey,
>                Map.Entry::getValue,
>                (e1, e2) -> e1,
>                LinkedHashMap::new
>              ));
> ```

So how do you sort `m2` and `m3` by the values of `m1`?

Easy: You supply a `Comparator` to `sorted()` that compares the values, e.g.

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> m1.get(e.getKey())).reversed())
```

You may have to explicitly specify the type of `e`, since the inference engine may get lost: `comparing((Entry<String, String> e) ->`

If you don't like `Comparator.comparing()` and `reversed()`, and the inference issue, you can just use a lambda.

Here is all the code, as proof of concept:

```
Map<String, Integer> m1 = new HashMap<>();
m1.put("c1", 3);
m1.put("c2", 24);
m1.put("c3", 12);

Map<String, String> m2 = new HashMap<>();
m2.put("c1", "A");
m2.put("c2", "B");
m2.put("c3", "C");

Map<String, Double> m3 = new HashMap<>();
m3.put("c1", 3.4);
m3.put("c2", 4.6);
m3.put("c3", 12.3);
```

```
Map<String, Integer> m1s =
        m1.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .sorted((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e2.getValue(), e1.getValue()))
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                                    (e1, e2) -> e1,
                                    LinkedHashMap::new));

Map<String, String> m2s =
        m2.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .sorted((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(m1.get(e2.getKey()), m1.get(e1.getKey())))
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                                    (e1, e2) -> e1,
                                    LinkedHashMap::new));

Map<String, Double> m3s =
        m3.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .sorted((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(m1.get(e2.getKey()), m1.get(e1.getKey())))
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                                    (e1, e2) -> e1,
                                    LinkedHashMap::new));
```

```
System.out.println(m1s);
System.out.println(m2s);
System.out.println(m3s);
```

*Output*

```
{c2=24, c3=12, c1=3}
{c2=B, c3=C, c1=A}
{c2=4.6, c3=12.3, c1=3.4}
```

Notice how `e2` and `e1` are reversed in the lambdas to cause descending order.

Of course, it would be much better to use the **Object-Oriented** features of Java and only have one `Map` to objects with three fields for the values.

Comment: This is all very well but it doesn't actually sort the Map.

Comment: @EJP It actually does sort the Map. Of course, you have to redo the sort any time you add/update a value, but this is the closest you can get to a Map sorted by value. Never said it was efficient, but it is what it is ...

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for helping. I like your approach, but I think that this line is doing not exactly what I expected  in m2s and m3s:
 **.sorted((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(m1.get(e2.getKey()), m1.get(e1.getKey())))**

It seems like it sorted m2s and m3s  maps based on VALUES of m1s map, and not KEYS. I need it to sorted by keys of m1s map. How to create such comparator?

Comment: @Bilberryfm You said *"I need to sort all 3 maps based on **values in** map with name **m1**"*. That's what this code does: See "*Output*". Values of `m1` in descending order is `24, 12, 3`, so keys must be in order `c2, c3, c1` in **all 3 maps**.